# Twitter HTTP Requests: 403 error

Tags: python, twitter, urllib

I want to send some HTTP requests to Twitter in Python in order to create a sign in for Twitter users for my app. I am using urllib, and following this link: https://dev.twitter.com/web/sign-in/implementing.

But I am unable to do this. I guess I need to authenticate before requesting a token but I don't know how to do that.

Code:

```
import urllib.request
req = urllib.request.Request("https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authenticate",
headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
html = urllib.request.urlopen(req).read()   //after this statement im 
                                              getting the error
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<pyshell#5>", line 1, in <module>
     html = urllib.request.urlopen(req).read()
    File "C:\Python34\lib\urllib\request.py", line 161, in urlopen
      return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
    File "C:\Python34\lib\urllib\request.py", line 469, in open
      response = meth(req, response)
    File "C:\Python34\lib\urllib\request.py", line 579, in http_response
      'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
    File "C:\Python34\lib\urllib\request.py", line 507, in error
     return self._call_chain(*args)
    File "C:\Python34\lib\urllib\request.py", line 441, in _call_chain
     result = func(*args)
    File "C:\Python34\lib\urllib\request.py", line 587, in http_error_default
     raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
    urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden
```

Comment: Although it's not an answer to your question, try the requests library (http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) instead of urllib.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you go to the url with a browser  it shows you that you need a key:

> Whoa there!
>   There is no request token for this page. That's the special key we need from applications asking to use your Twitter account. Please go back to the site or application that sent you here and try again; it was probably just a mistake.

If you go to [this link](https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/reference/post/oauth/request_token) it will let you choose one of your apps and 
it will bring you to a signature-generator that will show you the request settings.

To get a request_token you can use [requests_oauthlib](https://requests-oauthlib.readthedocs.org/en/latest/):

```
import requests
from requests_oauthlib import OAuth1


REQUEST_TOKEN_URL = "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token"
CONSUMER_KEY = "xxxxxxxx
CONSUMER_SECRET = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"

oauth = OAuth1(CONSUMER_KEY, client_secret=CONSUMER_SECRET)
r = requests.post(url=REQUEST_TOKEN_URL, auth=oauth)
print(r.content)
oauth_token=xxxxxxxxxxxxxx&oauth_token_secret=xxxxxxxxxxx&oauth_callback_confirmed=true
```

You then need to extract the oauth_token oauth_token_secret:

```
from urlparse import parse_qs
import webbrowser

data = parse_qs(r.content)
oauth_token = data['oauth_token'][0]
oauth_token_secret = data['oauth_token_secret'][0]
AUTH = "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize?oauth_token={}"
auth = AUTH.format(oauth_token)
webbrowser.open(auth)
```

A webpage will open asking to *Authorize your_app to use your account?*

For python 3 use:

```
from urllib.parse import parse_qs


data = parse_qs(r.text)
oauth_token = data['oauth_token'][0]
oauth_token_secret = data['oauth_token_secret'][0]
```

Comment: when i entered "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token" thi url in browser.
it says : 'bad authentication data'

Comment: No prob, I will add the last part when I get a chance later.

Comment: im not able to install urlparse pckge in python 3.4.
giving error

Comment: @mystry, sorry forgot you were using  python 3 edited.

Comment: yess.........a webpage opened, but its giving a message you mentioned above.
"whoa............"

Comment: Try the code again.  I made a mistake with the first code which is probably what you used

Comment: yupp........its done, please tell me aftrclicking 'authorize app' button...where shld i redirect it?

Comment: I wil have a look later when i get back on my computer and edit.